# How to update tile image with an online image getting through Tile Notification in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

i'm getting tile notification from server. Here i'm also getting image url of an online image. But i'm not able to show it on tile. Please solve the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can update your tile whenever you receive a notification, whatever the notification type may be.

First you just create your app tile dynamically , or you just let the user to pin your app in start screen.

And when you receive a Notification, parse the data and use this code to update your tile

```
  ShellTile TileToFind = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();

            StandardTileData NewTileData = new StandardTileData
            {
                BackgroundImage = new Uri(string_url_of_your_image, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
                Count =int_NotificationCount,
                BackTitle = string_title,
                BackContent = string_content,

            };

            TileToFind.Update(NewTileData);
```

Check this, hope this will help you.
Thank you.

Comment: Noorul , Thanks for the reply.
but when i recieve tile notification , how would i get notified ? Because i dont see any event for tile notification like we have "ShellToastNotificationReceived" event for toast notification.

Comment: Hi have you tried this one,`pushChannel.HttpNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<HttpNotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_HttpNotificationReceived); ` create this event after push channel register and let me this event is triggering or not while the tile notification arrives. Here that event `private void PushChannel_HttpNotificationReceived(object sender, HttpNotificationEventArgs e)
        {//do your stuf here}`

Comment: Hi @Pushpen actually in my app I use Raw notification and i am getting this PushChannel_HttpNotification triggered, and i am raising a toast notification there and tile update in that event.